# Changing Tab pane tabs programmatically in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am using tab panes defined as

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#personal" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#guardian" data-toggle="tab">Parent/Guardian Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#education" data-toggle="tab">Educational Background</a></li>
    <li><a href="#recommendations" data-toggle="tab">Study Prospects</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="personal"></div>
    <div class="active tab-pane" id="contact"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="guardian"></div>
</div>
```

It can be seen that i have selected Contact as First selected Tab, however when I refresh the page< on full page load it automatically changes tab to Personal that is First tab.

Is there any way i can manually switch tabs via javascript etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript set the one you want active and remove the other active one.

Comment: @Doomenik You didn't read the question. the problem is at page load it automatically selects the first tab. even tho i have put active on second tab

Answer (score 19):

There is a solution to change the tabs, so you will need to:

1. Keep the last tab some where.
2. Call the below function when the page refresh.

This how you can call it:

```
activeTab('tab1');

function activeTab(tab){
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Comment: implies a specific layout, and does not work with pills, for example.  `$('#' + tab).tab('show');` is enough

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need.

HTML:

```
<li id="contact"><a href="#contact"   data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('contact').classList.add('active'); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of Uwe Keim's answer, this is how you would accomplish his solution in angularjs (which I had a need for) - in case this helps someone:

```
 $timeout(function () {
            angular.element('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabname + '"]').tab("show");
        }, 0);
```